# Laravel unique validator not working for a URL string field

Tags: laravel, laravel-5.4

Running into an issue with the Laravel validator. I can not seem to catch a unique value that is in the database with the below validation rules. Is there something specifically with a URL that would be causing this? It goes past the unique validation piece and just errors out at the MySql level as it is trying to insert. Have not seen anything about URL fields, and from what i have been looking at the code looks correct (maybe i am loosing it - who knows ;) )

Here is the input: http://sub.domain.com

validator:

```
// Validate the incoming request
$validator = Validator::make($request->all(), [
    'original_url'  => 'required|unique:redirect_urls,original_url',
```

migration:

```
$table->string('original_url')->unique();
```

Thanks

Citti

Comment: awwww I am loosing it! What is happening is. I was entering in: sub.domain.com with no http://  - only i have a addProtocol function that checks and adds if it is missing AFTER the validation! so in the DB it is with protocol and PostMan has no Protocol! ugh! one of those nights! Sorry all!

Comment: @recoverymen table name is right. My F up here! was minipulating the data passed after the validation which is why it was erroring on the insert and not at the validation step. :\